# How do I register filters for dynamically-generated jinja2 templates in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am new to Flask. I am trying to generate my template dynamically so that I can make a request via AJAX and append rows to a table:

```
@app.template_filter('my_multiplier')
def my_multiplier(n):
  return n*10

@app.route('/')
def index():
  content = [1,2,3,4,5]
  tmplate = get_template()
  html = tmplate.render(content=content)
  return render_template('index.jinja2',html=html)


def get_template():
  html = Template(u'''\
    {% for n in conent %}
    <tr><td>{{ n | my_multiplier }}</td></tr>   
    {% endfor %}''')
  return html
```

I get an error: TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'my_multiplier'

What am I doing wrong? (The template renders fine if I exclude the filter)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you register the filter?

```
environment.filters['my_multiplier'] = my_multiplier
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the @app.template_filter('my_multiplier') registers the filter, no?

Answer (score 7):

Adding some info because I found this while googling a similar issue.

Current answer from https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/templating/#registering-filters:

> 

**Registering Filters**

> If you want to register your own filters in Jinja2 you have two ways
> to do that. You can either put them by hand into the jinja_env of the
> application or use the template_filter() decorator.
>
> The two following examples work the same and both reverse an object:

```
@app.template_filter('reverse')
def reverse_filter(s):
    return s[::-1]
```

> ---

```
def reverse_filter(s):
    return s[::-1]
app.jinja_env.filters['reverse'] = reverse_filter
```

> In case of the decorator the argument is optional if you want to use
> the function name as name of the filter. Once registered, you can use
> the filter in your templates in the same way as Jinja2’s builtin
> filters, for example if you have a Python list in the app context called
> mylist:
>
> ```
> {% for x in mylist | reverse %}{% endfor %}
> ```

For the above example that would mean that llamawithabowlcut is correct and the OP's code should work as shown.

I have tried to rebuild the described use-case, but I am not sure where the OP got the `Template` class from - the complete code would have been more helpful here.

Comment: Broken link no longer works.

Comment: @kontur Link is fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*EDIT*: looking back on this some months later, this is probably more of a hack than a solution. It works though, if you're okay with hacks.

For me using version 2.7.2, the documented way did *NOT* work:

```
environment.filters['my_multiplier'] = my_multiplier  # didn't work
```

That probably worked in older versions.

Instead I found this way by looking at the code:

```
from jinja2 import environment
environment.DEFAULT_FILTERS['name'] = filter_function
```

If someone has a documentation link, feel free to add it.

Comment: Can you explain which files you're putting this code in, please?

Comment: I'm using `jinja2` by itself so I just put it anywhere that's run before `jinja2` parses anything. I don't know where to put it for `flask` since I don't use that, I expect that any file that's run on startup should work.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue while using the app factory with blueprints configuration, and defining the template filters in a different module. I expect a lot of others will eventually run into this too when moving to production and serving application via WSGI.

If you import the module containing your custom template filter definitions inside the create_app function, the filters will register and be available in all templates.

```
#__init__.py
def create_app(config):
app = Flask(__name__)
with app.app_context():
    from app.my_module_dir import my_custom_template_filters_file
    # initialize extensions and
    # register blueprints here
return app
```

You'll need to import current_app since app is no longer globally available in this configuration

```
#app/my_module_dir/my_custom_template_filters_file.py
from flask import current_app as app
@app.template_filter('my_multiplier')
def my_multiplier(n):
    return n*10
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution if you're using the application factory pattern is to implement a similar interface to that of many Flask extensions, using an `init_app` method to allow dynamic registering of the filters with an app instance.

This way you can define your custom filter functions in a separate module, and register them in the app factory, allowing you to use them on any templates in your app.

For example:

```py
# app/util/template_filters.py

def my_multiplier(n):
  return n * 10


# A list of all of the template_filter functions to add in `init_app`
FILTERS = [my_multiplier]


def init_app(app):
    """Register the template filters with an app instance"""
    for func in FILTERS:
        app.add_template_filter(func)
```

```py
# __init__.py
from app.util import template_filters

def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    template_filters.init_app(app)

    # Perform rest of app setup here...

    return app
```

Note: This will always register the template filters using the function name. If you wanted to give them different names, you could instead specify `FILTERS` as a `dict` mapping from the desired filter name to the filter function.

```py
FILTERS = {'custom_function_name': my_multiplier}
```

and update the loop in `init_app` to:

```py
    for func_name, func in FILTERS:
        app.add_template_filter(func, func_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, if you use that decorator from any other module than the one in which `Flask` app is defined, it doesn't work. Taking the weirdness to the next level, it works in `behave` tests but not in the browser. This seems to be also the case for context processors and not just filters.

Looking at the decorator code this shouldn't be the case though.

Comment: That is so true even with flask 1.0 and very weird.